# I need a regex to extract a specific character between delimiter

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I need a regex to extract a specific character between delimiter, the specific character is ~ and the delimiter is ".

This is some example text :

```
~104.7866 ~"~A.SITI FATONAH "~2014/06/23
```

and

```
0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NURLINI ( 341676 ) ~ "~2016/05/18
```

I want to delete the ~ between two ", so the output is

```
~104.7866 ~"A.SITI FATONAH "~2014/06/23
```

and

```
0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NURLINI ( 341676 )  "~2016/05/18
```

I'm planning to use regex_replace in sql to replace the ~ but I cant find the right regex

Comment: Can there be multiple `~`s inside the quotes?

Comment: As identified by **@CertainPerformance**, the tricky case would be multiple `~`s within a pair of `".."` quotes; otherwise replacing `"([^~]*)~([^~]*)"` with `"$1$2"` should suffice [I'm talking about `regex` in general; never used `nsregularexpression`]

Comment: There is also the issue of having the input looking something like this `a"b"c"d"`. Would you consider `c` to be inside quotes? Because technically, it's not.

Comment: @CertainPerformance there is only one ~ inside the quotes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Im going to use regex_replace in sql

Comment: Is it Oracle SQL? PostgreSQL? MS SQL? In case of the first two, the `"(.*)~(.*)"` => `\1\2` will work if you have just a single pair of quotes in a string and there is always 1 `~` to remove.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its for bigquery

Comment: If `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, "(\"[^\"]*)~([^\"]*\")", "\\1\\2");` does not work for you (note it is very hacky for the current requirements), you will need to look for other ways than regex.

Answer (score 1):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '~104.7866 ~"~A.SITI FATONAH "~2014/06/23' str UNION ALL
  SELECT '0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NURLINI ( 341676 ) ~ "~2016/05/18' 
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'("[^"]*)~([^"]*")', r'\1\2')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure there's just two `"` on the string, you may use something similar to this (I used Oracle for the test, but almost any dbms should have concat, substr and intstr-like functions)

```
SELECT 
col as col_before,
concat(
substr(col, 1, instr(col, '"')),
concat(
regexp_replace(substr(col, 1+instr(col, '"'), instr(col, '"', 1+instr(col, '"'))-instr(col, '"')-1), '~', ''), 
substr(col, instr(col, '"', 1+instr(col, '"')))
)) as col_after


FROM (SELECT '0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NU~RLIN~I ( 341676 ) ~"~2016/05/18' as col FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1) t
WHERE 1=1
```

The basic idea is to split the string into 3 pieces, searching for `"`. Then replace `~` on the middle one, and then concat the 3 pieces again.

This can work even with several `~`.

```
COL_BEFORE = 0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NU~RLIN~I ( 341676 ) ~"~2016/05/18
COL_AFTER  = 0.0 ~ 0.0 ~"ENI NURLINI ( 341676 ) "~2016/05/18
```

Just for reference, if the engine would support PCRE regexes, this regex may also work, even removing several `~` [(?:(?:^[^"\n]*)")?\K([^"~\n]*)~?(?=.*")](https://regex101.com/r/2zT27u/3/)

Anyways it seems that Google query [uses re2 engine](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#regexp_match). So since [lookahead is not supported on re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). You'll have to stick with the first method.